# Get product category

Tags: bigcommerce

I have a BigCommerce site, and I need to split up the `products.featured` products into their respective categories.

I have tried using [this model](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/category-resources#Category), but it only gives me one category at a time.

Is there a way in Stencil to get the categories and their related products?